# Can I let my tortoise play outside while it's raining?

Tags: health, tortoises, outdoor

From this [topic](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/taking-care-correctly-tortoise-jabuti).

I have 20-year old Red-footed tortoise ("jabuti" type), and I would like to know if it would be a problem to let my tortoise outside in the rain, and what consequences might happen if it is a problem.

Comment: As long as it is warm enough it should not lead to any issues. If you are worried or not sure how the temperature will be during/after raining then bring it in

Comment: When its rainning, it more likey 18C to 23C or 64.4F to 73.4F

Comment: I don't know the exact temperature range

Answer (score 4):

As long as the weather doesn't get too cold, and sunshine is not continously absent, then your tortoise should be okay outside.

I remember from the last question your tortoise was a red foot tortoise, which naturally lives in rainforests. The high humidity level caused by the rain shouldn't be a problem for a rainforest tortoise. On the other hand, in summers if the weather is really hot then be sure to provide shaded cooler areas in the enclosure. You also want to provide a constant opportunity to soak, especially if it gets dry in the summer.

**Never** expose a tropical animal to a weather where other animals would hibernate. Tropical animals do not hibernate but they do become less active in colder weathers.

Keep in mind different tortoises have different needs mostly determined by their original homes. For example savannah tortoises like Leopard tortoises have been known to not do well in South Florida due to the humidity, though some keepers maintain them successfully, they say it's because they have been captive hatched in Florida and have acclimated. Nevertheless, be sure to provide similar temperature and humidity to what your tortoise naturally gets.